# IP Camera with embedded Linux won't connect to internet using ethernet

Tags: linux, networking, embedded

I have an IP Camera from Thundersoft with a Qualcomm Snapdragon 625 chip inside that runs a Linux distribution. It is extremely limited in terms of available commands, and I can't install any new commands without reflashing it (and I'm trying to avoid that).

I'm trying to connect the camera to an external machine learning API, to process the frames from the camera, but I can't connect the camera to the internet and I don't really know how to address the problem.

I tried connecting it through an ethernet cable (it works perfectly on my computer), but when I run `ifconfig` it returns:

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0A:F5:27:C8:C4  
      inet6 addr: fe80::20a:f5ff:fe27:c8c4/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:268 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:22048 (21.5 KiB)  TX bytes:536 (536.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0E:C6:8E:EE:C6  
      inet6 addr: fe80::20e:c6ff:fe8e:eec6/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1497 errors:3 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:3
      TX packets:17 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:861688 (841.4 KiB)  TX bytes:1502 (1.4 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:448 (448.0 B)  TX bytes:448 (448.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0A:F5:27:C8:C4  
      inet6 addr: fe80::20a:f5ff:fe27:c8c4/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:284 errors:0 dropped:1140 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:27096 (26.4 KiB)
```

What should I do to diagnose and solve the problem?

[EDIT AFTER COMMENTS]

The camera has two modes: USB and LAN, and they can't work at the same time. So in USB mode there's no dhcp client (or at least no process called dhc), but when I run ps in LAN mode (with a program that runs on startup and logs to file, because I don't have access to shell on LAN mode), I get no output, so I don't really know the processes running. About the manual IP assignment, I've tried a few things I found, but I think the camera overwrites the configurations later, because the files change after reboot.

My network does have a DHCP server.

Comment: The camera is not getting any IP address.  What does it have as a GUI for configuration?

Comment: I don't have any GUI, I only have shell access via USB

Comment: _I can't connect the camera to the internet ... I tried connecting it through an ethernet cable_ - so, the camera has an ethernet port, and you can connect to the camera to get a shell - yes? Can you call `ps` in the shell? If not, is `/proc/` populated with entries (especially directories that have numerical names)? This is to find out whether a DHCP client is running on the camera. In any case, can you manually assign an IP address?

Comment: Actually, about the DHCP client, it's difficult to know. The camera has two modes: USB and LAN, and they can't work at the same time. So in USB mode there's no dhcp client (or at least no process called *dhc*), but when I run `ps` in LAN mode (with a program that runs on startup and logs to file, because I don't have access to shell on LAN mode), I get no output, so I don't really know the processes running. About the manual IP assignment, I've tried a few things I found, but I think the camera overwrites the configurations later, because the files change.

Comment: "_I tried connecting it through an ethernet cable (it works perfectly on my computer)_" - is that the cable that works perfectly, or the camera connected to your computer?

Comment: The cable works perfectly! I'm currently writing this comment only connected to that cable.

Comment: Your camera appears to have a wired and a wireless interface. Have you activated a DHCP client on the device, and set it for the correct wired/wireless? (You do have a DHCP server on your network...?)

Comment: I don't really know if the network has a DHCP server, but I think it probably does... It's my office network. How can I check?

Comment: How does your PC get its IP address?

Comment: Actually, with DHCP :), so the network does have a DHCP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to try is to assign an IP address manually,

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.45.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

then use `route` to make sure that route is also set. Finally do the same on the PC it is connected to, using `192.168.45.2`.

Now check with `ping` if they can reach each other.

If they can't, next step is to figure out how the IP cam uses the bridge `br0`; possibly it should get the IP address instead, if `eth0` is a port in the bridge.

As soon as anything works, you can think about DHCP and how to automate it.